# Ruby: gem installed in wrong directory

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I am fairly new on Linux(using Ubuntu 10.10). I'm having some problem trying to install Rails 3.0.5 to the correct gem directory.

I have a root installation of Ruby (1.8.7) which I accidentally installed (which probably had a version of gem along with it) and RVM which I purposefully installed to manage Ruby versions.  I am able to default my Ruby version using RVM, no problem.

But when I attempt to install rails using the command:

```
gem install rails
```

it installs rails on the root gems directory which is: `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems`

but I want to install rails in the RVM directory instead: `/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems`

Some how, even after doing `sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems`.  The bad gem is still there.  I determine that by doing a `whereis gem` (correct function?). Which returns `/usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/bin/gem /usr/share/man/man1/gem.1.gz`

Now, how do I get rid of the bad gem and install the correct gem within RVM?

BTW, my GEM_PATH is `/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3:/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global:` which makes this more mysterious.

Any suggestion is appreciated,

Thanks
:)

Comment: Okay, after fiddling around with it more: uninstalled the root Ruby (1.8.7) by doing `sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems`. I should have gotten rid of the bad ruby/gem but no, somehow I still have two versions of gem is still in my system 1.3.7 and 1.5.2 (one of them could be from JRuby or something else though which I haven't touched).  Can anyone tell me which is the correct directory for gem to be in for a RVM install?  In ~/.rvm? or something like /var ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that could be wrong:

1. Your default interpreter is not what you think it is:

Make sure you run: `rvm --default use 1.9.2`

After this run: `ruby -v` to make sure you really do have the right ruby as your default ruby. If you do then `gem install rails` should work fine.

1. Your ruby interpreter did not install correctly (or RVM itself did not install correctly - unlikely):

It could be that your rvm did not install correctly, although this is unlikely. More likely your ruby interpreter did not install correctly. I suggest uninstalling and then reinstalling, while it installs observe closely for any errors/warnings when compiling and then installing the interpreter and then the gems that RVM installs by default (rake, rubygems). You'll probably see an error in one of these steps which likely means you're missing a library that is needed for ruby or the gems to install properly.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to install rails in the RVM directory you just have to run this :

> rvm gem install rails

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing all ruby/rvm/gems related thing and start afresh.  I used rvm (non sudo) to install everything and making sure that all ruby gems end up in the .rvm directory under my user directory.

Answer (score 0):

If `rvm --default use 1.9.2` gives you this error:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

It means you don't use login shell or you have to do `/bin/bash --login` first.
Found this solution at [stackoverflow: rvm installation not working: “RVM is not a function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function)