# Following Hartl's tutorial (Chap. 1.2.2) I get stuck setting up gems with rvm: "RVM is not a function"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In chapter 1.2.2 of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial we are using rvm to install rails.
Following the first few steps is no problem.
But when I get to this command:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@rails3tutorial2ndEd --create --default
```

I get this response.

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

I did a lot of research before posting this question. But could not find one that addresses my problem specifically.
I'm using linux under Ubuntu (in a VM on Windows 7).
Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest using rbenv over rvm. What is your system ruby? `ruby -v`

Comment: Also, have you worked through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function

Comment: Following the above link solved my question. There was a lot of material at that link. The simple step that was required was to "use a login shell" as described here: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

Comment: Problem NOT solved. Please see my comment below. Sorry for the false success notice.

Comment: if you're just trying to get 1.9.3 to work on your machine, I'd suggest using rbenv, or compiling it from source instead of using rvm. Can you tell me what ruby -v returns on your machine?

Comment: ruby -v returns: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]

Comment: I ended up using JohnnyFive's script (see below) and it resolved my problem.

Comment: By the way, JohnnyFive's script does use rbenv. I'll have to learn more about this.

Comment: the good news is that you got it working. The bad news is that you wasted all that time (but hey you learned something!), because you already had 1.9.3 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above is one way to fix it, although RVM says you should instead change your shell settings.

Press ctrl+alt+t to bring up the terminal, and then go to edit >> profile preferences >> title & command tab, then select "Run Command as Login Shell".

That should work as well.

Comment: I have done all of the steps at the other StackOverflow question that is similar. And I have carefully done the suggestions here. Still, when I run "bundle install" in my rails app folder I get the

Comment: My Ubuntu is: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: After changing the setting, you have to restart the terminal. Did you do that? Also, it might be useful for you to paste the cli up to that point, as well as the output of: `ls ~/.rvm`. I agree that using RBENV or just installing it yourself might be easier, RVM is not required for the tutorial at all.

Comment: I just spent the last 3 hours writing a script to install ruby, rails, and rubygems.. because it was fun. If it happens to help you, that's great, if not keep trying! [RailsSetup](https://github.com/johnny5ive/Rails-Setup)

Comment: Well JohnnyFive - your script did the trick. It was fun working with it and I learned a few things along the way. In the end when I know run 'bundle install' in my "FirstRails App" directory, it completes with no warning at all about rvm is not a function. I think I am out of the woods on this one and I can proceed with the Hartl tutorial.

Comment: @Will Great, glad it worked. Feel free to upvote my answer. Also, I updated the script to install fix a few errors and install RubyGems into the installed Ruby directory. Feel free to look at the changes. It's a good idea to understand what's happening, and not just copy/paste. Feel free to message me if you want information and want to look deeper into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not yet installed RVM correctly.

Make sure that you source RVM from your .bash_profile or .bashrc file.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

This is what I have in my .bash_profile for RVM to work. (After adding this restart your console or type `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: That line is in my .bash_profile file but it does not seem to be running because I also have my desired prompt set here (PS1= ..) and I am not getting that prompt. I'm learning linux and I'm not clear what profile files are being run when I open a terminal window besides the system one.

Comment: The comment above linking me to another stack overflow question looks very helpful. I missed it on my earlier search. I will follow through with that posting and see if it resolves my question.