# RVM is not a function in Raspbian RVM Installation

Tags: rvm, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm looking for a solution to the "RVM is not a function" issue when installing RVM on Raspbian using LXTerminal.  The following thread discusses workarounds for this issue:

[rvm installation not working: "RVM is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function)

One solution would be to start the terminal in "login mode" by doing /bin/bash --login, but this does not help on Raspbian because it uses LXTerminal.  Other people have suggested putting the following line at the end of your .bash_rc file:

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

...which seems to work.  Just wondering if (a) the above workaround is legit and will not screw anything up and (b) if anybody has found a more elegant solution for RVM on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the best solution is to run it with:

```
lxterminal -e "bash -li"
```

It will make the terminal use an `login` and `interactive` shell.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but when in the root application directory for a ruby on rails application it stopped working, I added this 'source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm' to my .bashrc file which worked in the /home/user/ folder and the root ruby on rails application folder