# How do I install ruby 2.0.0 correctly on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I have successfully installed `rvm`, but when I run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Or:

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

I have the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/oneiric/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: This question clearly falls within the scope defined by the community: "software tools commonly used by programmers", reopen.

Comment: should ideally be migrated to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 192, accepted):

follow below steps

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev
cd /tmp
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p481.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-2.0.0-p481.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p481/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Confirm SUDO needed for apt-get's and make install

Comment: these steps are for root account, so don't need a `sudo` :)

Comment: @PravinMishra what output when you type on terminal `which ruby` ?

Comment: path of ruby installed- "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby" This is for my rvm.

Comment: Newest 2.0 source: http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p451.tar.gz  or newest 2.1: http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.1.tar.gz

Comment: great, I added your script in one line in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29584352/1069083)

Comment: @Whatcould several important gems are not ported yet for 2.1.1 so there's no way to choose newes version in some cases.

Comment: I'm still at 1.8.7 after following those steps

Comment: `cd ../  && rm -r ruby-2.0.0-p481`

Comment: Links to newest stable source releases can always be found at https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Comment: I'm still 1.9.3 after this :(

Answer (score 56):

## Use `rvm` to install stable ruby:

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

or, if you have rvm already, get stable version:

```
rvm get stable
```

Install ruby and use the specific version of ruby (remember to use login shell)

```
/bin/bash --login
rvm install 2.0.0
rvm use 2.0.0
rvm rubygems latest
ruby --version
```

As found on t[he official RVM website](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

EDIT: 
 As @prem points out run this at first and follow the above steps **if there is a public key error**

`gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys \  409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

## Use `rbenv` to install ruby:

Install necessary dependancies:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev \
build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev \
sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Install `rbenv`:

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Install ruby:

```
rbenv install -v 2.0.0
```

Comment: some I followed steps and it was continuously falling then I run  rvm get and run these steps again and it worked

Comment: @Guru edited answer to upgrade rvm to stable version

Comment: If u stumble on public **key issues** run this `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3` and follow the above steps.

Comment: I finished the download and it worked fine. After the restart of my computer, an infamous message 'RVM is not a function' was shown when typing command `ruby` and `rvm use 2.0.0`. Here's the solution : [rvm installation not working: “RVM is not a function”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 32):

From the [travis-cli installation instructions for Ubuntu](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#other-unix-systems), the [Brightbox Ruby NG(NextGeneration)](https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng) ppa:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ruby2.1 ruby-switch
$ sudo ruby-switch --set ruby2.1
```

Comment: This worked for my Ubuntu 14, I would add also

`$ sudo apt-get install ruby2.1-dev`

that you will need for example if you want to install [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) which depends on RedCloth, that will complain when installing if headers (like ruby.h) are missing.

Comment: Need to update the first line: `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

Comment: Works on my machine :) On ubuntu trusty, vagrant. In case of 2.2dev you need: `apt-get install ruby2.2 ruby2.2-dev ruby-switch` and `ruby-switch --set ruby2.2`.

Comment: after install, i try install jekyll, but get this error `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h`

Comment: @ghanbari you may need the header files, they aren't packaged with the release (as only machines that compile software need them), try installing `ruby2.1-dev` if it exists, you are looking for a package named after the primary package with a `-dev` suffix.

Answer (score 7):

Although this answer was accepted, I would strongly recommend using rvm rather. I had nothing but trouble trying to install ruby without it. See e.g. this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Answer (score 3):

Any easy way to install ruby is with [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install). I had compile errors when building ruby from scratch, but `ruby-install` encountered no such problems.

*edit:* I've had problems with `rvm` in the past, and feel I should actively recommend against this. That's just me personally, though. I've had okay luck with `rbenv`, but always use it in conjunction with `ruby-install`.

Answer (score 2):

You have some ppa sources enabled that aren't available for your version of Ubuntu. Comment those out in your /etc/apt/sources.list , run sudo apt-get update , and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use **rbenv**

The first step is to install some dependencies for Ruby.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties
```

Installing with **rbenv** is a simple two step process. First you install **rbenv**, and then **ruby-build**:

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.0.0
rbenv global 2.0.0
ruby -v
```

[The original post on gorails.com](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04)

Answer (score 1):

I put **@PravinMishra**'s source into a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/ba9b64b160fe46e44aa1) and now you can simply use this one liner:

```
wget -O - https://git.io/vvkI4 | bash
```

**NOTE:** Don't trust my Gist blindly, download the file and look into it before you run it!