# How to set Ruby Environment in Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

```
~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

**Note:** I dont want to set the ruby path using **RVM**

[image]

Comment: How did you install the Ruby? From source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490591/how-to-install-ruby-2-on-ubuntu-without-rvm

Comment: I haven't installed RVM or Rbenv. My lib files direct to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems

Comment: If you don't want to use RVM. `ruby-build` is a good alternative and which requires almost no setup. https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How did you install your ruby? apt-get install ? I highly recommend using RVM it will make your life easier. But in General you can set up your Environment variables in Linux in a standard way:

To display current environment:

```
set
```

You can modify each environmental or system variable using the export command. Set the PATH environment variable to include the directory where you installed the bin directory with perl and shell scripts:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/username/bin
```

OR

```
export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin
```

You will need to check out the path of your Ruby file using

```
which ruby
```

Then to set it up:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
```

The ~/.bash_profile ($HOME/.bash_profile) or ~/.prfile file is executed when you login using console or remotely using ssh. Add the path to ~/.bash_profile file

Comment: let me check @Eki Eqbal

Comment: Hi @Eki Eqbal I dont want to use /Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin

Comment: You are NOT supposed to use the exact path, I'm just giving you an example. replace */Users/info/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin* with your output of the command *which ruby*

Comment: What is the result of 'which ruby' ? Please run it in your terminal and let me know.