# Conflicting packages on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sass

I was installing Sass on ubuntu for that I first installed Ruby and then Sass.  but when i tried sass -v it gave a deprecated message about currently install ruby1.9 version saying it will not be support in future. so i tried upgrading ruby version to 2.0 (2.3 is not being installed on ubuntu) using

> $ sudo apt-get install ruby2.0

But when checking the ruby version it still showed 1.9 so i tried with UN-installing Ruby1.9 then it showed a dependent library to uninstalled. I even did that but after that on installing ruby 2.0 again it gives error

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:
libantlr3c-antlrdbg-3.2-0 : Conflicts: libantlr3c-3.2-0
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should install it directly from source, like so:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev 
libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p451.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-2.0.0-p451.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p451/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

[Solution found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18490935/5168927)