# How to install Ruby on docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-machine, calabash-android

I am trying to install ruby on docker. I could install the 1.9 versions but it is not possible to install the latest version such as 2.2.0 and above. I am actually trying to set up calabash on docker. Have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222738/how-do-i-install-ruby-2-0-0-correctly-on-ubuntu-12-04). Whenever I try to install calabash-android in it getting the error

```
ERROR:  Error installing calabash-android:
luffa requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could start view a dockerfile starting with:

```
# 2016
FROM ruby:2.3.0

# 2020
# Import your ruby version
FROM ruby:2.7.1
# Install bundler gem
RUN gem install bundler
# Assign a work directory
WORKDIR /work
```

That would use the [docker image ruby](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/), with ruby already installed.

The 2020 version comes from "[Ruby version management with docker](https://thearjunmdas.github.io/entries/dev-with-ruby-docker/)" from **[Arjun Das](https://twitter.com/TheArjunMDas)**, mentioned by [ArMD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3540495/armd) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305861/how-to-install-ruby-on-docker/36306240?noredirect=1#comment115292354_36306240).

Comment: Thanks @VonC for your help. Can I manually install ruby when I am inside the container?

Comment: @muneermuhammed no: you would specify the installation of ruby in a Dockerfile in order to build an image with ruby installed, which then allows you to run a container in which ruby is available. You don't install anything directly in a container. Plus, if your Dockerfile starts with FROM ruby:2.3.0, you don't have to install ruby at all. It is already installed for you.

Comment: Can I simply run the command as RUN ruby:2.3.0 if my docker file starts with FROM ubuntu:14.04 ?

Comment: @muneermuhammed no, RUN is for shell commands, not docker image names. You would need, in your Dockerfile, to reproduce the content of https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/c88f3a67da720bfa9fb1717960d90fd5db11c757/2.3/Dockerfile in order to install ruby: it is done on top of a Debian Jessie distribution but might work on top of an ubuntu one.

Comment: @muneermuhammed a simlper alternative is to use the `FROM ruby:2.3.0` directive, and see if what you are doing on top of that is compatible with a Debien jessie distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107732/discussion-between-muneer-muhammed-and-vonc).

Comment: I always start my ruby setup with the dockerfile mentioned here - https://thearjunmdas.github.io/entries/dev-with-ruby-docker/

Comment: @ArMD Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 20):

If you're starting `FROM` a different base Docker instance, you can simply `RUN` commands that install Ruby from your base instance's package management system. For example, [this GitHub Gist](https://github.com/dockerfile/ruby/blob/master/Dockerfile) shows how to use `apt-get` to install Ruby on a Ubuntu instance:

```
# Pull base image.
FROM dockerfile/ubuntu

# Install Ruby.
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y ruby
```

And [this Gist](https://github.com/dockerfile/ruby/blob/master/Dockerfile) shows a Dockerfile that's configured to install RVM and Ruby on a Ubuntu instance:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

# basics
RUN apt-get install -y openssl

# install RVM, Ruby, and Bundler
RUN \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm requirements"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install 2.0"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc"
```

Comment: Looks like link to gist with Dockerfile for ruby via rvm is wrong. Also it may be required to add curl to `# basics` like `RUN apt-get install -y openssl curl`. [link to gist I've tried](https://gist.github.com/malovme/ad28917f1d86fac20b9c2634fbd0a048)

Answer (score 16):

This makes ruby available for any future RUN command and not just bash:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
RUN \
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests curl bzip2 build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  curl -L https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/archive/v20180329.tar.gz | tar -zxvf - -C /tmp/ && \
  cd /tmp/ruby-build-* && ./install.sh && cd / && \
  ruby-build -v 2.5.1 /usr/local && rm -rfv /tmp/ruby-build-* && \
  gem install bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Comment: took me two days of faffing around to get here, my environment is docker using image openjdk:8 to use in android build pipeline

Answer (score 4):

Low reputation so I can't comment inline (all those years of lurking, sigh), but in case anyone else happens across this while searching for ways to install old ruby versions to docker, I found [@grosser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578968/4575793) very helpful - it worked where trying to install via RVM simply wouldn't, at least for me.

I would, however, recommend using the recommended approach for installing ruby-build - the following worked for me:

```
<prior steps>
RUN git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git && \
  PREFIX=/usr/local ./ruby-build/install.sh && \
  ruby-build -v 2.4.1 /usr/local && \
  gem install bundler -v <VERSION HERE> --no-ri --no-rdoc && bundle install
<following steps>
```

Key point here is that this keeps you up to date with ruby-build instead of being hard-coded to the 2018-03-29 version as in a previous @grosser's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60290031/4575793) and [@grosser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578968/4575793), I've managed to set up mine in a similar, if a bit more unpacked way:

```
# Install Local ruby
RUN git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv \
  &&  echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc \
  &&  echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

ENV HOME /home/jenkins # Change this dir as needed.
ENV PATH "$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
ENV RUBY_VERSION 2.6.3

RUN mkdir -p "$(rbenv root)"/plugins \
    && git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build

RUN rbenv install $RUBY_VERSION

RUN rbenv global $RUBY_VERSION && rbenv versions && ruby -v

# RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash # Uncomment this to get rbenv to validate your setup.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use things like `bundle install` and don't use a base image with pre-installed devtools like Ubuntu, you need to install these packages:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev ruby-bundler build-essential
```