# Installation is not happening according to Docker file

Tags: android, docker, sdk, dockerfile, calabash-android

I am running a calabash-android test using docker. When I build the container with my docker file it seems like nothing executing except the first line. When I check whether ruby installed or not it shows the ruby version. Apart from that nothing is working. I am adding the docker file structure here.

```
############################################################
# Docker file to run Calabash for android automation testing.
############################################################

FROM ruby:2.1-onbuild

# install Android SDK dependencies

RUN apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

# Install android sdk
RUN wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23-linux.tgz
RUN tar -xvzf android-sdk_r23-linux.tgz
RUN mv android-sdk-linux /usr/local/android-sdk
RUN rm android-sdk_r23-linux.tgz

# Install Android tools
RUN echo y | /usr/local/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk --filter platform,tool,platform-tool,extra,addon-google_apis-google-19,addon-google_apis_x86-google-19,build-tools-19.1.0 --no-ui -a

#install calabash-android

RUN gem install calabash-android

ENV ANDROID_HOME /usr/local/android-sdk
ENV ANDROID_SDK_HOME $ANDROID_HOME
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/platform-tools
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

I have followed this [link](https://github.com/bprodoehl/docker-android-dev/blob/master/Dockerfile) to implement the Docker file. Since this is for the first time I am setting up docker for android haven't the faintest idea whether it is proper or not. Someone please help to fix the issue. All kinda helps are appreciated.

Comment: What docker version are you using? What is the output of a `docker build -t xxx .`?

Comment: Thanks  VonC. Docker version 1.8.3

Comment: I could build the image and run the docker. But apart from ruby nothing seems like installed. I have removed every thing and repeat the whole steps  from the scratch.

Comment: What command line are you using to run that image as a container?

Comment: docker run xxxx and `docker exec` following that.

Comment: The output of docker build would still be helpful in seeing why the installation of the various packages failed.

Comment: But it is not raising any errors. Is there any flaw in the syntax of my docker file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108144/discussion-between-muneer-muhammed-and-vonc).

Comment: No chat possible at work, sorry.

Comment: That's ok. I am sorry I forget to tell you that I get this response for the docker build "Step 0 : FROM ruby:2.1-onbuild 
# Executing 4 build triggers 
Trigger 0, COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app/ 
Step 0 : COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app/ 
Gemfile: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get this response for the docker build

```
Step 0 : FROM ruby:2.1-onbuild 
# Executing 4 build triggers 
Trigger 0, COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app/ 
Step 0 : COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app/ Gemfile: no such file or directory
```

First, as long as the docker build does not execute *all* the steps, it is perfectly expected to not see anything installed.

Second, the [`ONBUILD` directives](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild) from the ruby:2.1-onbuild are made to complete the image when building a new one from said image.

[As I mention before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36306240/6309), you can try first using

```
FROM ruby:2.3.0
```

That does not require extra onbuild trigger.

Comment: Thanks. Let me have a try.