# Installing rvm hangs on mac os x

Tags: macos, rvm

I've been here kind of a while:

```
The ports tree has been updated. To upgrade your installed ports, you should run
  port upgrade outdated
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkgconfig, apple-gcc42, libiconv, libyaml, libffi, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, curl-ca-bundle, sqlite3, zlib, ncurses, gdbm............
```

When running:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Not exactly sure why or useful debugging steps to take here.  How to troubleshoot this?  Will update this post as I find useful information.

Per log it got this far when I ctrl+c'ed:

> --->  Cleaning pkgconfig
>   --->  Computing dependencies for apple-gcc42
>   --->  Dependencies to be installed: cctools llvm-3.2 gcc_select ld64
>   --->  Fetching archive for llvm-3.2
>   --->  Attempting to fetch llvm-3.2-3.2_1.darwin_12.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/llvm-3.2
>   --->  Attempting to fetch llvm-3.2-3.2_1.darwin_12.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/llvm-3.2
>   --->  Installing llvm-3.2 @3.2_1
>   --->  Activating llvm-3.2 @3.2_1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try:

tail -f .rvm/log/MOST_RECENT_FOLDER/package_install_gcc46.log

Comment: If this is right it's a better answer than mine, so accepting it.

Answer (score 10):

Just wait even longer.  Took me about a half hour, hour maybe?  I haven't figured out how to get more verbose output on which steps are taking place, but "waiting longer" is a valid step to try.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - mines taking absolutely ages too.

Comment: Thanks, mine is taking so long I'm going to watch a movie.

Comment: @AndrewPlummer - mine taking ages as well-- what movie did you end up watching.. :)

Comment: yeah what'd you guys end up watching? I'm also installing and need a movie to watch in the meantime

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself (Mac OS X Mavericks). Took nearly an hour to complete. Installation was successful. Looks like the only thing it installed was `gcc466`. Hasn't solved my `RVM is not a function...` issue with `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`.

Comment: Likewise, took a very long time to install gcc46. But it all worked in the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function    <------- how to solve the RVM is not a function error.

Answer (score 5):

First, install gcc46

```
brew install gcc46
```

This took 18.9 minutes to build but once built, I was able to install rvm in minutes.

Comment: I thought the build froze, thanks for the build time info, will wait some more this time (while my Mac is melting away building whatever gcc46 is)

Answer (score 2):

```
rvm requirements
```

was taking forever for me, so I stopped the process, and installed each requirement myself with brew individually, this gave me a better indication of what the hell was going on, when it was downloading what and what it was doing...

## Mac

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool pkgconfig apple-gcc42 ...
```

## Debian

```
apt-get install autoconf . . .
```

## Fedora

```
yum install autoconf . . .
```