# Not able to install ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-2.0

I am facing weird issue. I installed ruby latest version 2.0.0 using RVM on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
 \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

But when i restart my computer,

```
ruby -v
```

gives

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

And when i try to run this:

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

It gives

```
 Already installed ruby-2.0.0-p247.
 To reinstall use:

rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

Even on reinstall ruby -v gives ruby 1.8.7. I am not getting why ruby 2.0.0 is not getting installed and it reverts back to ruby 1.8.7 on computer restart.

Can anyone help me on why this happening? Thank you.

Comment: `rvm use 2.0.0; ruby --version`

Comment: Do you want to install it systemwide as your new ruby or using RVM? `rvm use 2.0.0` is the RVM command for using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate 2.0.0 as well:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

To mark it as the default:

```
rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```

As for your "RVM is not a function" problem, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function).

Comment: Above command gives RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to another Stack Overflow question about that.

Comment: Worked! followed the link of question u gave. Thanks :-)