# incorrect rvm ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ruby-2.0

When I do bundle install in a rails app I get:
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

```
> rvm install 2.0.0

Already installed ruby-2.0.0-p247.

> which ruby

/home/myuser/.rvm/bin/ruby
```

Previously I had included the following in ~/.bashrc:

```
PATH=$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH

> which -a ruby

/home/hector/.rvm/bin/ruby

/usr/bin/ruby
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `rvm`

http://rvm.io/rvm/install

make a default ruby to load:

```
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

or just switch to a desired one:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

use the one installed on your system:

```
rvm use system
```

for **rvm is not a function** see here: [rvm installation not working: "RVM is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function)

the first line of the accepted answer might help you fast:
**you are not using an login shell**

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell rvm which version of ruby to use.

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

Comment: I tried but I got: RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.

Comment: @user2140139 did you follow these instructions?

Comment: I've run into that /bin/bash --login issue with rvm before.  I can't seem to recall how I got around it though...

Answer (score 0):

Check with this also

Just type `'/bin/bash --login'` in your terminal (after restarting your terminal), then type the comand `'rvm use 2.0.0'` (for e.g.) and it will start using the same version.

Just execute the command `'ruby -v'` to confirm that the RVM is using the updated version of Ruby.