# RVM is not a function - Login Shell does not work

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm

I installed RVM on my Linux Mint computer, and when I run

```
$ rvm use
```

I get an error message saying "RVM is not a function". I tried to run as login shell, but when I started a new terminal window, I had a `PATH:command not found` error and the rvm error persisted. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9336596/981616 possible duplicate

Comment: In this question, I am asking specifically about Linux Mint 15.

Comment: Can you show us the error full?

Comment: When you got the error,just run it `/bin/bash --login` and use your rvm command... what happened after following my instructions..let me know..

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.

Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.

Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

[image: Here you can see how to configure your terminal.]