# how to use rvm in shell scripting

Tags: bash, rvm

is it possible to load rvm in shell script . can any one give an example of it.
when i try a shell script . i am using ubuntu system

```
#!/bin/bash
rvm use 1.9.3
```

it gives me error

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rvm installation not working: "RVM is not a function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 17):

You can just include rvm in your script by doing:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

then rvm should be available to your script,

Comment: Make sure you are using bash to execute the script and not sh.

Comment: how to use bash . i created a file names qst.sh and written a code in it.

Comment: instead of "sh qst.sh" use "bash qst.sh"

Comment: This answer is great and helped me too, so thanks. I just want to clarify that this line should be added *in addition to* your line that calls rvm. At first I thought I was supposed to use this in my command instead of just `rvm`. In my case I wanted to do a `rvm use system`, and so I needed to add the `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` but still call `rvm use system` on a different line.

Answer (score 5):

for simply executing a command against a RVM managed Ruby (or system Ruby) do :

```
rvm 1.9.3 exec camper_van
```

this assumes `rvm use 1.9.3` and `gem install camper_van` happened previously which provides the `camper_van` executable

NOTE: RVM is expected to be loaded already - which it usually is for scripts started under your user (the `RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...'` confirms it's there already).

Answer (score 1):

```
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
# Loading RVM *as a function* is mandatory
# so that we can use 'rvm use <specific version>'
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # First try to load from a user install
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
  echo "using user install $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # Then try to load from a root install
  source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
  echo "using root install /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
else
  echo "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"
fi
```

Comment: whats the output of command `type -fP rvm`. The given snippet is part of shell script.

Comment: Amol's code requires bash, make sure you are not executing your script with plain sh.

Comment: when i type in terminal the output of type -fp is /home/gaurav/.rvm/bin/rvm.  actually i am new to script. when i write echo type -fp rvm then the same command get printed

Comment: Adding this to by bash script, this snippet echos:  "using user install $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm".  Then, when the next line tries "rvm use..." right back to the old "rvm is not a function" error.  How to we do something in our Bash script to "make rvm a function" so we can actually do something with it - like set the ruby version?

Comment: Thanks a ton @jbr my issue was fixed after running it through bash. Cheers