# Cannot recognize rails in ubuntu terminal, but in aptana terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, aptana

I followed this to install ror,

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

after that, everything works fine(i think so),

but the strange thing is,

if i command `rails` in ubuntu terminal

it says install apt-get

[image]

however in aptana terminal,

it runs fine,

[image]

can i ask why it doesn't work in ubuntu default terminal?

do i have to setup some kind of path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change a few terminal profile preferences before you can start using rvm through gnome terminal.[This](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal) article contains more information.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function) may also help.