# RVM Failing to install Ruby on OS x 10.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to use RVM to install Ruby and Rails on my OS X Mavericks laptop.  When I run:

> rvm requirements

I run into :

```
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system..jeffwomble password required for 'port -dv selfupdate': 
........
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_update_system ',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/jeffwomble/.rvm/log/1395493335/update_system.log
checking for xcode-select... /usr/bin/xcode-select
checking Mac OS X version... 10.9.2
checking Xcode location... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/base':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
shell command "cd /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/base && CC=/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-tclpackage=/Library/Tcl --with-install-user=root --with-install-group=admin --with-directory-mode=0755 --enable-readline && make && make install" returned error 77
DEBUG: Error installing new MacPorts base: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: shell command failed (see log for details)
+ return 1
+ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I've got the latest version of Xcode installed.  I've tried to run:

> Xcode-select --install

But I'm told that the command line tools are not available on the server.

I noticed this line:

```
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
```

but I think the file should be /usr/bin/llvm-gcc

What do I need to do?

Comment: try add symlink `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I could try a symlink I tried to run mac ports from the command line.  I got a  '-bash: port: command not found" error.  I downloaded and installed macports manually, and after that everything has been working great.

Answer (score 0):

Install HomeBrew first, and then run:

rvm requirements

Worked for me on Mac OS Mavericks.
(tip form [How install ruby 2.1.0 on OS_X 10.9 using rvm? ( No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360825/how-install-ruby-2-1-0-on-os-x-10-9-using-rvm-no-binary-rubies-available-for))