# rvm switches to old ruby version after reboot against default set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

Every time I startup my computer (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), it loads ruby 1.8.7, even when ruby 2.1.1 is set as `=* - current && default` (upon `rvm list`).

To change the version I use `rvm use ruby-2.1.1`

However, every single time I use the `use` command, I get the popular error message `RVM is not a function...`.

So, again every single time, I have to follow the same steps, i.e. first type `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` and only then switch to ruby-2.1.1 with `rvm use ruby-2.1.1`. Then, also Rails switches automatically from 2-something to 4.1.4.

1. How can I convince my machine to stay with the head versions even after reboot?
2. What does the `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` do and how do I understand this syntax? (I can't see any command here, really - just the parameter -s)

Comment: Maybe you will find answer here. Same error as yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make rvm known to your bash sessions simply by updading your .bashrc :

   echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc.

(Info: Your problem was that you invoked the previous scripts and the changes they made lasted only for your current bash session. Now it's executed every time you open bash)

1. $HOME stands for /home/<>. So in your home folder there is a .rvm directory where a scripts directory is included. The "command" here is the script rvm. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Please correct me if I am wrong, but if I wanted to understand and write myself lines like `[[ -s "$HOME...`, I should read a lot on bash scripting? Any adhoc-like source appreciated.

Comment: Not really. It's pretty straight-forward scripting in bash for every-day tasks like this. What are your needs? What do you want to script for? There are many bash-tutorials on the web, as well as  Linux Certifications (LPIC-1 , LPIC1-2).

Comment: Well, above all I am trying to learn Ruby (on Rails), but every now and then similar issues arise slowing me down. So I figured out it would be useful to properly acquaint myself with the UNIX environment first. Unsurprisingly, it is an immense domain, and even determining what to learn is very hard. I do not know any pro to supervise me, so maybe you can recommend some reading on skills that come handy in an advanced everyday use? I learn alone, which makes it cloggy.

Comment: Yeah sure. You could try [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/) or [this](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/) tutorial. Generally, if you search at google for Unix tutorial / Linux Basics etc you ll get what you want. Don't start with bash scripting. Have a look at the Unix operating system, and then you can look scripting (bash) tutorials. If you are a fan of coursera I would recommend [their course](https://class.coursera.org/webapplications-001) for Ruby on Rails. I ve taken this lesson and I believe you should have a look if you re interested in learning Rails

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that RVM is not loaded when you open a terminal, you have to manually add the source at each instance of the Terminal.

You need to add rvm source to the bashrc or bash_profile to resolve this issue.

Open terminal:

echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile

Or this (if using non-login shell):

echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc

This will add the path to RVM to load at each Terminal instanciation (close & re-open a terminal after you did this).

Comment: Thanks. I posted answer to my question as summary to the state of things. Could you kindly tell me where do I learn more on commands such as `source` or `export`? I couldn't find man pages for them. Is this bash scripting? (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)