# Why rvm needs login shell?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, rvm

As far as I know, rvm is a set of bash scripts. Why it need login shells? Which property which only exists in login shells is necessary for rvm?

Related post: [rvm installation not working: “RVM is not a function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function/)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you think RVM needs a login shell? I can find nothing about such a limitation in the RVM documentation. Quite the opposite in fact. It works perfectly fine in any sort of interactive shell, not just a login shell. It isn't activated by default in non-interactive shells, but again, activating it is a simple one-liner, and it's clearly documented with examples.

Answer (score 2):

Your RVM config line (`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm ...`) likely located is in `.profile`, which is only read when your `bash` is on login-shell mode. There are other config files that are read in other modes as well, like `.bashrc` when the shell is interactive, but non-login or file defined by `$BASH_ENV` when it is non-interactive.

See INVOCATION section in [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for more details.

Comment: That is to say, if I add the config line to bashrc, then the non-login shell would work the same?

Comment: @endle Yep it should work. It won't work for non-interactive scripts though (like bash scripts).