# rvm is not reading .ruby-version on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have a rails 5.1 app, here is my .ruby-version

```
ruby-2.5.0
```

Here is the output of rvm list

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]
```

When I cd to "current" (deployed using Capistrano) I and I run the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec ruby --version
```

I get

```
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
```

I thought .ruby-version was what triggers which ruby version is used.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on using 2.5..0 as the default ruby version for your app run this on the server

```
rvm use --default 2.5.0
```

Its giving you 2.4.0 because its set up as the default and current ie =* means it is what will be used.

Also since you are deploying with capistrano and are using rvm you should consider using this gem.

https://github.com/capistrano/rvm

Comment: tried, i get RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work

Comment: this happens when rvm is not available in the shell did you install rvm as a single user or multi-user?

Comment: don't know, any idea how to fix?

Comment: @user1130176 check this on how to resolve it if you have any more problems reach out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336596/rvm-installation-not-working-rvm-is-not-a-function

Comment: run this `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` the run the `rvm use --default 2.5.0` command tell me how this goes

Comment: ```echo  "[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] &&  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"" >> ~/.bashrc``` to fix this permanently

Comment: ok thanks, so just to clarify, .ruby-version does nothing on a production server?

Comment: in my experience .ruby-version has worked when I changed into the directory on development but on production hasn't been straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs you can set the ruby version explicitly, it also may likely be your server - for instance if you are using nginx you have to explicitly state your path in the nginx config file to your ruby version - but that all depends on your production configuration

https://rvm.io/rubies/default

```
$ rvm --default use 2.1.1

$ ruby -v

ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

Comment: Tried this i get RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work

Comment: Have you installed rvm on the machine? If so make sure it’s in your PATH, what server are you using in production?