Running an application's commands, like rake, from a standalone ruby script but rvm not taking into account gemset
I am on Ubuntu 18.04.
I have a Rack-based application at /home/jignesh/webapps/my-app-1 (henceforth this will be referred to as app_root).
app_root contains following files

.ruby-version

3.3.3


.ruby-gemset

my-app-1


Rakefile

task_1 definition

task_2 definition

I want to run those tasks from a stand-alone ruby script which is located at /home/jignesh/Desktop/my_script.rb (henceforth this will be referred to as my_script).
my_script looks like following:
RUN_RAKE_TASKS = [
  'task_1',
  'task_2'
].freeze

def run_rake_tasks
  this_script_dir = Dir.pwd

  Dir.chdir('<app_root>')

  RUN_RAKE_TASKS.each do |task_name|
    cmd = "bundle exec rake {task_name}"

    system(cmd)
  end

  Dir.chdir(this_script_dir)
end

Running that script I see the output
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

That's strange because I have ruby 3.3.3 installed and also gemset my-app-1 created and in it all my gems are installed.
So I opened a terminal and changed directory to app_root and ran bundle exec rake task_1 and it worked.
To investigate what is the problem with the script unable to find the gems I modified my run_rake_tasks method like following
def run_rake_tasks
  this_script_dir = Dir.pwd

  Dir.chdir('<app_root>')

  system('gem env')

  system('rvm gemset name')
end

and when I ran the script following was the output
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.5.17
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.3.3 (2024-06-12 patchlevel 89) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jignesh/.gem/ruby/3.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.3/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/jignesh/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3/bin
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3@global/bin
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.3/bin
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin


/home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3

Then I manually ran gem env and rvm gemset name commands on terminal and I got following output
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.5.17
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.3.3 (2024-06-12 patchlevel 89) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3@my-app-1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jignesh/.gem/ruby/3.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.3/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3@my-app-1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/jignesh/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3@my-app-1
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3@my-app-1/bin
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.3@global/bin
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.3/bin
     - /home/jignesh/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin



my-app-1

Comparing that with the output generated by the script I concluded that the process in the script is not taking into account the rvm gemset which is automatically
done when running commands from terminal. So I modified my run_rake_tasks method like following
def run_rake_tasks
  this_script_dir = Dir.pwd

  Dir.chdir('<app_root>')

  ruby_version = `cat .ruby-version`
  ruby_gemset = `cat .ruby-gemset`

  # `chop` important because the backtick output contains newline chars at the end.
  ruby_version.chop!
  ruby_gemset.chop!

  rvm_use_gemset_command = "rvm use #{ruby_version}@#{ruby_gemset}"

  system(rvm_use_gemset_command)

  system('gem env')

  system('rvm gemset name')
end

When I ran the script, in the output I saw following:
  RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

  You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
  Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
  Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

Searching for that error I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105199/936494 and based on that I modified my method like following
def run_rake_tasks
  this_script_dir = Dir.pwd

  Dir.chdir('<app_root>')

  system('source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm')
  system('type rvm | head -n 1')

  ruby_version = `cat .ruby-version`
  ruby_gemset = `cat .ruby-gemset`

  # `chop` important because the backtick output contains newline chars at the end.
  ruby_version.chop!
  ruby_gemset.chop!

  rvm_use_gemset_command = "rvm use #{ruby_version}@#{ruby_gemset}"

  system(rvm_use_gemset_command)

  system('gem env')

  system('rvm gemset name')
end

When I ran the script, in the output I saw following:
  sh: 1: source: not found
  rvm is /home/jignesh/.rvm/bin/rvm

Searching for that I found following
source command not found in sh shell
"source" in ruby subshells
Based on them I made changed
  system('source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm')

to
  system('. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm')

When I ran the script, in the output I saw following:
  sh: 10: /home/jignesh/.rvm/scripts/rvm: builtin: not found
  rvm is /home/jignesh/.rvm/bin/rvm

Searching for that I found following
"builtin: not found" when I source a script via PHP passthru()
Based on that changed
  system('source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm')
  system('type rvm | head -n 1')

to
system("/bin/bash -c '. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && type rvm | head -n 1'")

When I ran the script, in the output I saw following:
  rvm is a function

But despite that the subsequent commands
  system(rvm_use_gemset_command)

  system('gem env')

  system('rvm gemset name')

emitted RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work. and the gem env and gemset as mentioned before.
I have understood the problem as when running the commands from script the rvm gemset is not being found.
So how do I make my script work so that I am able to successfully run the desired rake tasks and possibly other run other commands as well which I can do by manually running them from terminal?
Thanks.

Each call to Kernel#system is run in its own subshell for example 3.times { system('echo $$')} will show 3 different process ids. While there may be workarounds (I honestly didn't try) is there a specific reason the script needs to be written in ruby? It seems to me, based on what the script actually does, making this a bash script would be easier and more appropriate.

Each system command spawns a new shell so what you can do is use the rvm binary and the commands you need to run in a single command. like system("~/.rvm/bin/rvm use ruby-3.3.3@my-app-1; bundle exec rake {task_name}")

Based on the comment by @engineersmnky (dated Aug 7, 2024 at 17:45) I decided to run the rake tasks through a bash script and run that bash script itself through my ruby script. Sharing here the code I implemented
run_rake_tasks.sh
rubyVersion=$(cat ../.ruby-version)
rubyGemsetName=$(cat ../.ruby-gemset)

#echo $rubyVersion
#echo $rubyGemsetName

rvmUseGemsetCommand="rvm use ${rubyVersion}@${rubyGemsetName}"

#echo $rvmUseGemsetCommand

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

$rvmUseGemsetCommand

#gem env

#rvm gemset name

echo "Starting running rake tasks."

rakeTasks=('task_1' 'task_2')

for str in ${rakeTasks[@]}; do
  #echo $str

  bundle exec rake $str
done

echo "Finished running rake tasks."

# Like following you can also run other ruby scripts which may depend on gems in the gemset. 

echo "Starting running ruby script rs_1."

ruby rs_1.rb

echo "Finished running ruby script rs_1."

Note: The bash script must be made executable. For that use following command from the directory in which the script is present:
$chmod u+x run_rake_tasks.sh

Then I modified my run_rake_tasks in following manner:
def run_rake_tasks
  this_script_dir = Dir.pwd

  Dir.chdir('<app_root>')

  system('./run_rake_tasks.sh')

  Dir.chdir(this_script_dir)
 end

and it ran the rake tasks as expected. Hope this helps others having similar needs.
Thanks.
